# Keycloak: Can not read users realm roles as admin cli when calling the admin rest api

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth, keycloak, openid-connect

I use keycloak 11 as openid connect provider for my spring boot services. Everything works fine so far.

Problem:

I have a service that uses a webclient. It is nested in my service and uses client auth with the `admin-cli` client. That works. When I do a get on /users/userId, I get the user representation. The problem I have now is that the Realm Roles of the user are not added to the representation.

In the [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource) this parameter is mentioned as String [] and marked as optional in the UserRepresentation.

I thought that if I configure the `Service account roles -> Client Roles -> realm-management -> realmAdmin` , the client should be able to view the whole user output.

But if I use postman and call the api as ali-admin, it is not included in the JSON reponse.

I also tried to add the attribute in my KeycloakUserRepresentationModel

```
public class KeycloakUserRepresentation {

    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private Boolean emailVerified;
    private Boolean enabled;
    private Map<String, List<String>> attributes;
    private String[] realmRoles;
```

and execute the request. The array realmRoles is always null.

Can you tell me what do I have to configure to read the users realmRoles as admin-cli?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** The `/auth` path was removed starting with [Keycloak 17 Quarkus distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902419/1366871). So you might need to remove the `/auth` from the endpoint calls presented on this answer.

---

First, request a token from the `admin-cli` client on behalf of the `admin` user (or a user with a-like privileges):

```
curl    -d "client_id=admin-cli" \
        -d "username=$ADMIN_NAME" \
        -d "password=$ADMIN_PASSWORD" \
        -d "grant_type=password" \
        https://$KEYCLOAK_IP/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

then to get the list of users associate with a given realm role use the previous token on the call to the following endpoint:

```
GET <KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms/<YOUR_REALM>/roles/<ROLE_NAME>/users
```

From the `JSON` response you can check if your user belongs to that list.

Alternatively, you can call the Rest Admin API to

1. get the user, and then extract its `ID`;
2. get the roles associated with that user by using its `ID` in the call to the endpoint: `GET <KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms/<YOUR_REALM>/users/<USER_ID>/role-mappings`

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there are two ways of doing it.

First: the url dreamcrash mentioned:

```
GET <KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms/<YOUR_REALM>/roles/<ROLE_NAME>/users
```

Here you get all users with the requested role.

Second:

```
GET <KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms/<YOUR_REALM>/users/<USER_ID>/role-mappings
```

Here you get realm and client mappings for the specific user.

I think solution 2 is the better approach because you only load the information for a specific user. Solution 1 loads all users and their whole account information. This can lead to a performance lack.

What I don't understand is that the general /users/id endpoint does not return most of the optional parameters in the UserRepresentation response object. I think that is so annoying to always find a route somewhere in the docs. I know it is an open source project but I think this should be fixed or at least explained how to configure keycloak to get the information.

Comment: Yep, it is a very annoying. But on the other side sometimes you just want the users without all the roles. Btw the solution 2 that you are mention, was the alternative solution that I wrote, I just update now the answer to explicitly mention the endpoint

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that. Again, thanks for the solution.